# C# WPF - Set only one Excel Worksheet on ReadOnly

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

So I need to open an Excel file, add a new sheet, work with it and then set ONLY this worksheet to ReadOnly.

Is there a way to set only one worksheet of an Excel workbook on ReadOnly?

```
OpenFileDialog OptimaExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
            OptimaExcel.Title = "Optimas Excel wählen";
            OptimaExcel.Filter = "Excel file|*.xlsx";
            if (OptimaExcel.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application OptimaExcelApp;
                OptimaExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
                OptimaExcelApp.Visible = true;      //Später auf false                   
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                string filepathname = myPublicPath + OptimaExcel.SafeFileName;
                Workbook OptimaWorkbook;
                OptimaWorkbook = OptimaExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepathname, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                Worksheet myBlockWorksheet;
                myBlockWorksheet = (Worksheet)OptimaWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();      
                myBlockWorksheet.Move(Missing.Value, OptimaWorkbook.Sheets[OptimaWorkbook.Sheets.Count]);
                myBlockWorksheet.Name = "Projektdaten";
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Im using this code and it works, but I just dont have any idea how to set only one Excel sheet to ReadOnly

Comment: Try to set with dataentrymode false which contains worksheet.Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Worksheet.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetclass.protect?view=excel-pia) method

```
            myBlockWorksheet = (Worksheet)OptimaWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();      
            myBlockWorksheet.Move(Missing.Value, OptimaWorkbook.Sheets[OptimaWorkbook.Sheets.Count]);
            myBlockWorksheet.Name = "Projektdaten";
            myBlockWorksheet.Protect(missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, in method parameter 3 number parameter is ready only parameter to open excel.

[For Details check on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Workbooks_Open_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_)

```
var imaWorkbook = OptimaExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepathname, missing, false, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

Comment: as per your requirement you want to open readonly excel sheet, that will be working